# Set permissions using chmod whilst in the wrong directory

Tags: chmod, system-recovery

I was doing a magento patch via Terminal and ran the following commands whilst in / rather than /public_html

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
```

Is there an easy fix for this, or have i messed up my server?

Comment: What OS you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I had some similar issue but not from root folder :s

If you use a RPM-based distro, this can be done using the `rpm --setperms` command.
it would be painfully reverting one by one the packages, on Debian-like system `apt-get --reinstall install` is your friend.

I'm not shure it will work through all directory thought

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty well hosed your server. The quickest way to recover is going to be to reinstall your OS and restore your backups. You do have backups, right?

Comment: Yes, I've got backups. Only a fool doesn't :)